# I'm stuck in my Image Matching algorithm i.e. with Perspective Transform of opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to build a matching algo that lets you match 2 images which have handwritten stuff in them. It was all working great for the 1st 10 comparisons but later for some images it got stuck at the "**cv**.**PerspectiveTransform**" and started returning errors.  Do help me out with this as this is a major element in my algo.

```
if len(good) > min_match_count:    
   src_pnts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1,1,2)
   dst_pnts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1,1,2)

   M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pnts, dst_pnts, cv2.RANSAC, 10.0)
   matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()
   h, w = crop_image.shape
   pnts = np.float32([[0, 0], [0, h-1], [w-1, h-1], [w-1, 0]]).reshape(-1,4,2)
   dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pnts, M)
```

I just want a to know if this could be solved and make it robust so that i do not get stuck at places and if not are there any alternative solutions to this.

The error I'm getting>>> Error: OpenCv<3.4.4>C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\matmul.cpp:2270: error <-215:Assertion failed> scn + 1 == m.colsin function ' cv::perspectiveTransform '

Comment: Please include the error messages in your question.

Comment: Error: OpenCv<3.4.4>C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\matmul.cpp:2270: error <-215:Assertion failed> scn + 1 == m.colsin function ' cv::perspectiveTransform '

Comment: min_match_count is an integer variable

Comment: Add this error to the question by editing the question so it is more clear please.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  Done it

Comment: You should assert that `findHomography` is able to estimate a homography each iteration and that `min_match_count` is >= 4, although a larger number would be more robust depending on your application. My guess is that `M` could not be estimated.

Comment: Thanks for the help, anyways, my min_match_count = 10     i do not understand why does it fail for certain images.  Also, is there an alternative method to perform the same step.   cv2.warpPerspective, any idea if this is a better option?